# Codigniter transaction in with multiple ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to begin codeigniter transaction in one ajax call and want to commit it in another ajax call how would I do this

**Method Calling on First Ajax Call**

```
function method1(){
    $this->db->trans_begin();
}
```

**Method Calling On Second Ajax Call**

```
function method2 {
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    } else {
        echo  "hey good";
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        $results['status']=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Not getting any error i just want to ask that is it possible that begin transaction in one ajax call and commit it in another ajax call will this work or not

Comment: Keep track of  `GET` or `POST` in session, and for every ajax request check session whether called first time or not, if first time then call method1, second time call method2